# While loop inside switch but before the first case statements in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

What is this called and how is it possible?

```
    switch (state_in->step){
        while (1){
            case step_a:
                // do something and fallthrough

            case step_b:
                // do something and fallthrough

            case step_c:
                // do something and fallthrough

            case step_d:
                // do something and fallthrough
        }
    }
```

snippet is from `cdecode.c` of the [libb64 project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libb64/). The `state_in->step` variable is not touched inside the loop, and code seems to iterate `step_a`->`step_b`->`step_c`->`step_d`->`step_a`->`...`.

It seems as if `switch` acts as a smart `goto` statement, pointing inside a `while` loop? I would like to know how this thing works, but google only gives me `switch` inside a loop in C.

Comment: Its called Duff's device.

Comment: Thanks @AviBerger , that answers the first question,
now how is this a valid `C` syntax?

Comment: It is peculiar and surprising that it is legal. There are explanations in the linked duplicate post and on wikipedia. [And here are some messages about it by its inventor](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/duffs-device.html)